# AzCopy uploading local files to Azure Storage as files, not Blobs

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azcopy

I'm attempting to upload 550K files from my local hard drive to Azure Blob Storage using the following command (AzCopy 5.1.1) -

```
AzCopy /Source:d:\processed /Dest:https://ContainerX.file.core.windows.net/fec-data/Reports/ /DestKey:SomethingSomething== /S
```

It starts churning right away.

But it's actually creating a new Azure **File Storage** folder called fec-data/reports rather than creating new blobs in the **Azure Blob** folder fec-data/reports I've already created.

What am I missing?

Also, is there anyway to keep the date created (or similar) values of the old files?

Thanks,

Comment: Try changing `file.core.windows.net` to `blob.core.windows.net`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But it's actually creating a new Azure File Storage folder called
>   fec-data/reports rather than creating new blobs in the Azure Blob
>   folder fec-data/reports I've already created.
>
> What am I missing?

The reason you're seeing this behavior is because you're uploading to `File` storage instead of `Blob` storage. To upload the files to `Blob` storage, you need to specify blob service endpoint (`blob.core.windows.net`). So your command would be:

```
AzCopy /Source:d:\processed /Dest:https://ContainerX.blob.core.windows.net/fec-data/Reports/ /DestKey:SomethingSomething== /S
```

> Also, is there anyway to keep the date created (or similar) values of
>   the old files?

Assuming you want to keep the date created of the blob same as that of the desktop file, then it is not possible. Blob's `Last Modified Date/Time` is a system property that gets assigned when a blob is created and is updated every time that blob is changed. You could however make use of blob's metadata and store file's creation date/time there.

Comment: Gaurav's answer was actually first but since it's in the form of a comment I can't flag it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to get the instance of the bob where you want to deploy the file 
    like :

```
 AzCopy /Source:d:\processed /Dest:https://ContainerX.blob.core.windows.net/fec-data/Reports/ /DestKey:SomethingSomething== /S
```

Blob: Upload
Upload single file

```
 AzCopy /Source:C:\myfolder/Dest:https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer /DestKey:key /Pattern:"abc.txt"
```

If the specified destination container does not exist, AzCopy will create it and upload the file into it.

Upload single file to virtual directory

```
AzCopy /Source:C:\myfolder /Dest:https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/vd /DestKey:key /Pattern:abc.txt
```

If the specified virtual directory does not exist, AzCopy will upload the file to include the virtual directory in its name (e.g., vd/abc.txt in the example above).

please refer the link :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy

[image]